# Referencing ASP.Net 5 from .Net 4.x assembly

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dnx

I want to reference my ASP.Net 5 code from a standard .Net 4.x assembly.

[image]

I have written a migration tool that moves data from an old MySQL database to a new MSSQL. It uses EF and does the job just fine.

Upon setting up the web solution I went for ASP.Net 5/MVC6/EF7 as RC is out and (despite the lack of documentation at this time) it seems like a cleaner and better approach than the previous. With the web project I decided to go with vanilla ASP.Net identity tables in SQL. This means that my migrator needs to migrate the "Users" table into the ASP.Net identity system, foreign keys (to users) in other tables needs updating, etc.

Now I expect to be re-running the migrator whenever I change stuff, so instead of keeping two models/dbcontexts updated (one in migrator and one in web project) I would normally reference the web solution and pull them in. However this doesn't work.

Having the models in a separate class library also seems problematic as I got compile time errors and the DNX command for EF migration/db update seems to fail.

The SO question "[How to reference an ASP.NET 5 project from another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886853/how-to-reference-an-asp-net-5-project-from-another-project)" does not apply as I do not have a project.json file in my .Net 4.x project. Can't find anything relevant on the Google machine either.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/621 has a discussion around the problem

Comment: Since you already found a GitHub issue on the topic, what exactly do you expect with this question here? It seems pretty clear to me from that issue, that referencing DNX projects from csproj is currently not possible.

Comment: GitHub issue was found after question was asked and it discusses a direct reference. I don't know if it would be possible with a PCL workaround or something similar. I haven't looked much into DNX yet.

Comment: You could simply build the DNX project and then reference the output DLL as a workaround.