# How to reference an ASP.NET Core project from a Full .Net framework Test project?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, mstest

In Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, I created an `ASP.NET Core` project based on the `Full .NET Framework` and a .net class library project that contains my domain model.

I then created a Unit Test project (with `ms-test`), in order to test my controllers and my domain objects. Here is the directory structure:

```
Proj
|-src
   |-WebProj
|-DomainProj
|-TestProj
```

I am able to reference the asp.net core web project as a dependency by using the References item under the test project.

**The problem is that types from the asp.net core project are not available in the Test project (type or namespace name cannot be found error).**

I have found the following question in stackoverflow: [How to reference an ASP.NET 5 project from another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32886853/1182189)
But it is not very helpful; creating a project.json file in the test project that references the web project did not resolve the types.

Should I create a separate .Net core test project in order to test the asp.net core project?

**UPDATE**
Here is the WebProj's project.json file:

```
    {
  "userSecretsId": "xxxxx",

  "dependencies": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.281",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "5.2.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "dependencies": {
        "CodeGenProj": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "DomainProj": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you cannot do this. why do you need to create full .net framework  test project? Why don't you create .net core test project with Xunit framework? Xunit is one of first frameworks that supports .net core. check [this](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html) out

Comment: Please post the project.json file from your .NET Core project.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I posted the project.json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your unit test project is a `csproj` and your web application is probably an `xproj`. Unfortunately, you cannot directly reference an `xproj` from a `csproj`. There is a [document in the dotnet/corefx Github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/target-dotnetcore-with-msbuild.md) that explains how to convert your web application to a csproj.

Related Issues:

- https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/89
- https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/6124