# Running .net core project from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a solution that has 3 projects. Project2 needs Project1 to be running in order to function normally (Project2 call some Apis in Project1).

```
Solution
|-- Project1
|   |-- Program.cs
|   |-- Startup.cs
|-- Project2
|   |-- Program.cs
|   |-- Startup.cs
|-- IntegrationTestProject
```

I can run the 2 projects together by changing the properties of the solution as shown in the below image and it worked fine:

[image]

What I want is a way to run Project1 from Project2 by code (from startup or from SomeService in Project2) and it will be great if I can also stop Project1 when I stop running Project2.

I tried this code and it didn't start Project1:

```
  string[] x = { };
  Project1.Program.Main(x);
```

**Edit:**

IntegrationTestProject is used to test Project2 Apis. So I created a `new TestServer()` from Project2.

When I run the integration test, some APIs succeeded (the one that only depends on Project2) and other failed (the one that calls Apis from Project1) because the server (Project1) is not reachable (it is down when test run).

If I run the integration test while running Project1, all test succeeded.

I tried to run a test instance of Project1 using `new TestServer()` and pass it to Project2. It worked for some Apis and I faced another problem that seemed not to be solved until I run Project1 and not a test instance of it.

So my only solution is to run Project1 when I start the integration test.

I made a .bat file that runs Project1 (by dotnet run) and then starts the integration test (by dotnet test) and it worked fine. But the problem with it is when running the integration test from Visual studio it didn't run Project1.

**Edit 2:**

This is a sample project that demonstrates the problem I faced: 
https://github.com/bilalseh/SampleSolution

1- If you run Project2 alone and call (Get: "/api/home") it will return a result.
If you call (Get: "/api/home/5") it will have a problem because this Api depends on Project1.

2- If you open visual studio and run the tests (2 tests) or run these tests from the command line by "dotnet test" 1 test will pass (testing: "/api/home") and one will fail (testing: "/api/home/5").

3- If you run Project1 and then start the tests both will pass.

4- I made a .bat file named "run test with temp server.bat" in the integration test folder. This file will run Project1 and then starts the tests and then stops Project1. If you run this file both tests will pass.

What I want is to find a way to starts Project1 either from Project2 or when I start the integration test.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and why?

Comment: The same thing as in the image but in code

Comment: Running the `Main` method *will* start Project1, but synchronously, in the currently executing thread, in the same process. That's not the same as the two projects running independently. Without knowing what the projects do, it's hard to know what to advise.

Comment: I would have thought you probably want a 3rd "startup" script to start each one in a separate context, rather than creating a direct dependency of one on the other. The Visual studio is the 3rd party script currently, so it would probably make sense to aim to replace that.

Comment: @JonSkeet If I run the 2 projects on the currently executing thread, can I still call the apis from Project1?

Comment: What do you mean by "call the APIs"? Are these Web APIs in project 1? Is project 2 also a web site? Do you want to host them in the same Kestrel instance (or IIS)? At the moment we have very little context here, which makes it hard to help you.

Comment: Project2 is a test project for project1. I know I can run an instance of project1 from project2 using new TestServer() but this is not my case. I want to run Project1 the same way when I use dotnet run for Project1

Comment: @Bilal So why is there a problem using "multiple startup projects"?

Comment: Because I didn't start the projects using Start button in visual studio. I run the tests and it starts Project2 only.

Comment: You mean you manually launch them outside of Visual Studio?

Comment: @john this is one case

Comment: Do you actually have to launch one from the other, or do you simply need both running? Would a bash/batch script which starts one and then the other suffice?

Comment: @John I used a batch file and it worked fine (It contains 2 commands: 1- run Project1 and 2- start test in project2). But the problem is that when I start the test from visual studio it didn't start Project1

Comment: You mean, using the "multiple startup projects" only one starts?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning all the details of my project. But I thought if I ask a more general question it will help me to get an answer quickly. In project 2 there are integration tests (using XUnit) and the visual studio has a tab for running the tests (different from Start button)
@John for answering your question when I use the Start button it runs the 2 projects but it didn't run the test. when I eun the tests from the test tab it only runs 1 project (project2) and same if I use dotnet test command.

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right it runs on the same thread and it blocks the code in Project2 from running. I run it on another thread and it worked. The only issue I have now is the CORS origins as I think.

Comment: Please put all of the information *in the question*. The fact that you're wanting to run integration tests against a web app makes a huge difference... you may well not want to run Main directly, but instead create the web host and control it from your integration tests. See https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime.org/tree/master/src/NodaTime.Web.SmokeTest for an example of this.

Comment: @JonSkeet There is another project than the test project which I need to do the same. Can I use the code mention in the question (running in another thread) in the Startup.cs or Program.cs? Will the two projects run normally in this case as I run "multiple startup projects"?

Comment: @BilalSehwail: Again, it really depends on the context. I'm afraid I can't give more help without a *lot* more information, which should absolutely be in the *question* rather than comments.

Comment: @JonSkeet I added all the details about my project and added all the points mentioned in the comments

Comment: We don't know how you started the web app from the integration test, or what you mean by "I faced a problem". If you could reproduce this with a [mcve], we could provide a concrete solution. Everything is easier when we're dealing with concrete code rather than abstract generalizations.

Comment: @JonSkeet I made and uploaded a sample solution which has the same problem I have, and I write what cases make the test pass and what cases will make it failed.

Comment: I'll have a look if I can at some stage, but it would definitely be a better question if we didn't have to download a zip file in order to understand the question. (A GitHub repository with the example would be better than a zip file, for example.) There's still a lot of vagueness here: "I faced another problem" is not a clear, specific description.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree it is not safe to upload a sample solution to the question so I created a repo and it replaced the zip file.
For "I faced another problem" the problem is with Bearer authentication (Project1 is giving and checking authentications of users in Project2. I don't need to use a TestServer instance of Project1 and pass it to TestInstance of Project2.

Comment: Why doesn't setting the build order work for you and start both projects? (your second screen shot)

Comment: @PaulStory It works when I start both projects. But when I start the integration test it will not start any project, it only starts a test instance from Project2

Answer (score 8):

You either add reference to the assembly of the project you want to start.

The other way would be with `Process.Start()` and put the path of your executable to run it

On the project that wish to open other project:

> Right click References-> Add references -> Solution -> check the
>   project you want to create -> OK

You might need to add extra references if the compiler ask you to (PresentationFramework, system.xaml ...) Or Make Project 2 Program.cs Public by adding the word "public" in front of "class Program".

And Add this
In Project 1 button...

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Project_2 pb = new Project_2()
    Process.Start(pb.returnPath() + \\"Project_2.exe");
}
```

EDIT : As I search in stackoverflow, your question similar as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886853/how-to-reference-an-asp-net-5-project-from-another-project)

Comment: Do you mean I publish Project1 to exe file and then run it when I start Project2?

Comment: Just publish project 1, and put the Project 2 link in a button in Project1. You cant run Project 1 from Project 2 if you do not give reference.

Comment: That will be a solution but it is not a best practice solution. User doesn't need to publish the Project every time he made a change in the project.

Comment: They have to publish. Otherwise, there is no change.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you want to go the microservice way. So, couple of principles:

1) you should be able to debug the services one at the time - if you debug service A that depends on service B, make a mock service B. Then test/debug service B on its own - if all parts work, the whole machine should work

2) if you want to RUN (not just debug), use Docker/Kubernetes for that. They will manage any restarts, crashes, updates etc. If you want to test the full system, still run docker deploy, then run integration tests on that

Each microservice is it's own thing, without any real dependency on others, so no shared databases, no crossrefences via DLL etc.

If you feel like that's overkill, don't split your app into microservices, make one big service - it will be easier to manage. At least until certain point when granurality shows its goodness